# Insert mode auto activated after text selection in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I have set up my Android Studio with all plugins I had before. I am facing a problem and I can not resolve it. The problem is when I am selecting a line to edit or delete the cursor then turns into insert mode and then I can not do anything like deleting or editing. How can I resolve this? I am using Android Studio 4.0.

This is the video link I uploaded it to show you the problem just 1 min video. This will clarify my statements.

[See The Problem in This Video](https://youtu.be/GV2FMG98AG0)

Comment: You probably need to press the insert key to toggle that.

Comment: i did that but its work for that moment, Then again its activated when i am selecting lines. See the video pls

Comment: Check please, is there anything set in Settings -> Keymap -> Editor Actions | Toggle Insert/Overwrite

Comment: that option is set to insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution here,
This made my day.....

[Solution Link](https://www.deadscript.net/insert-or-overwrite-mode-in-android-studio/)

[Solution Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSXCi41eNKk)

> Check for the first time if you didn’t activate the insert mode. Keyboard shortcuts for the android studio will not be the source of that bug. You have to check the Android Studio plugin to disable the one which causes the problem of typing.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to uninstall or disble the ideavim plugin and you're good to go.